# Font similar to Helvetica (but corners a bit rounded)

Tags: font-identification

Can somebody please help me in identifying the font used in the image. I had no luck with [WhatTheFont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0SAf.png). Notice that corners are a bit rounded. The letters serve on a large poster. Eventually I'd like to use that font on OS X so a good match with one of its available fonts would be best for my purposes.

[image]

Comment: Any more letters in that poster? Tough to get an ID from those two characters alone. Calibri actually isn't too far off from what you want, but its 'A' is definitely wider.

Comment: That's kind of a goofy S

Answer (score 2):

If you have a tool like Adobe Illustrator:

1. Type in Helvetica
2. Convert to Outlines
3. Increase Corner Radius

[image]

(For any serious type enthusiasts that can spot it, I used Source Sans Pro because I don't have Helvetica)

Answer (score 1):

The **S** is very similar to Stephenson Blake's **Grotesque No. 9**:

[image: Grotesque example]

http://www.fonts.com/font/urw/grotesque-no-9/regular

However this is slightly too thin. The **Bureau Grot** family develops Stephenson Blake's Grotesque and does include a fatter variant (middle of the fifth row):

[image: Bureau Grot]

http://blog.webtype.com/?p=2431

Answer (score -1):

It could very well be Alte Haas Grotesk, which is a slightly rounded-edged version of the pre-Helvetica Swiss grotesques.

[image: 1]

http://www.dafont.com/alte-haas-grotesk.font

http://webfonts.ffonts.net/Alte-Haas-Grotesk-Bold.font

Answer (score -3):

Introducing Helvetica Rounded. Helvetica, with a touch of rounded-ness.
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/helvetica-rounded/

[image]

Comment: The font shown is not nearly as rounded as Helvetica Rounded.